# Option and Future

Tags: scala, scala-option

I am in process of building ubercool application with amazing amount of abstractions.
Now I am going to design over-engineered EntityGetService.

First thing I want is a lot of abstract types, let say something like this:

```
trait EntityGetService[ID, ENTITY, CONTAINER] {
  def get(id: ID): CONTAINER
}
```

CONTAINER here is type of something that contains (or not contains) requested entity. Very similar to Option[ENTITY]. But the second thing I want, that CONTAINER also can be a Future[ENTITY].

So really I want to write trait like this:

```
trait EntityGetService[ID, ENTITY, CONTAINER <: Wrapper[ENTITY]] {
    def get(id: ID): CONTAINER
}
```

and specify it in such ways:

```
trait EntitySyncGetService[Long, Entity, Option[Entity]] {
    def get(id: Long): Option[Entity]
}

trait EntityAsyncGetService[Long, Entity, Future[Entity]] {
    def get(id: Long): Future[Entity]
}
```

Is there any way to do this without re-extending or mixing something to Option and Future?

It looks like Option and Future have a bit of in common (their both containers). Is it something related to monads?

Or this is just a product of my insomnia?

Answer (score 3):

Not commenting on the reasonableness of it all, you can use higher-order types :

```
trait WrappedGetService[ID, ENTITY, WRAPPER[_]] {
  def get(id: ID) : WRAPPER[ENTITY]
}
```

then you can declare a `WrappedGetService[Long, Entity, Option]`.

**update**: some references

The feature is called as *higher-order types* (possibly *higher-kinded types* too) or *types constructors*.

- In [the language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), it should appear mostly in section
  4.4, Type Parameters, but there will not be a lot about it, it works much like other type parameters.
- The feature was originally proposed in the paper [Generics of a higher
  kind](http://adriaanm.github.com/files/higher.pdf) The paper may not be implemented exactly as is in the
  language, but it should be very close. On the other hand, the collection library went another way, you may see why in [Fighting Bit Rot with Types](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2009/2338/pdf/09005.OderskyM.2338.pdf).
- you may have a look at the [scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/) library (not for the faint of heart). If you go that way, you might want to have a look at Haskell too.

Comment: Looks like this is what I was searching for. Can you point to some resource to read about this feature? Quick googling shows nothing usefull.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this through a bit of what I'd call "manual AOP".

First define some base trait to capture the concept of wrapping the result inside an `Option`, a `Future`, or any other container, together with a a method to actually do the wrapping:

```
import concurrent._

trait AbstractService {
  type Result[T]
  protected def result[T]( code: => T ) : Result[T]
}
```

Then specialize this base trait for the `Future` and `Option` cases:

```
trait SyncService extends AbstractService {
  type Result[T] = Option[T]
  // Returns the original result wrapped in Some, 
  // or None if it was null or an exception occured
  protected def result[T]( code: => T ) : Option[T] = {
    try {
      Option( code )
    } catch{ case ex: Throwable =>
      ex.printStackTrace()
      None
    }
  }  
}

trait AsyncService extends AbstractService {
  type Result[T] = Future[T]
  protected val execContext: ExecutionContext
  protected def result[T]( code: => T ) : Future[T] = {
    future( code )( execContext )
  }
}
```

Now you're good to go and can define your EntityGetService trait like this:

```
trait EntityGetService[ID, ENTITY] extends AbstractService {
  def get( id: ID ): Result[ENTITY] = result {
    ???
  }

  // add all the other method implementations here, taking care to 
  // wrap the method bodies inside "result"
}

// Now specializing EntityGetService as a sync or async service is just a matter 
// of mixing SyncService or AsyncService:

class EntitySyncGetService[Long, Entity] extends EntityGetService[Long, Entity] with SyncService
class EntityAsyncGetService[Long, Entity]( implicit val execContext: ExecutionContext ) extends EntityGetService[Long, Entity] with AsyncService
```